# Creating a view for 3 tables with a little complex relationships

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have 3 tables, "ruta", "track_ruta", "punto_ruta"
ruta has a relationship of one to many to track_ruta and another relationship of one to many to punto_ruta.
track_ruta has also a relationship of one to many to punto_ruta.
ruta means route in Spanish by the way.  So long story short a Route has tracks and tracks have points.  There can be points without tracks that belong to a Route.  That is why it is the way it is.
I need to retrieve and do searches according to dates on the points and I need to look for points of a route.
I had this as an sql sentence

```
select DISTINCT p.* 
from PuntoRuta p, Ruta r, TrackRuta t 
where ((r.codigo=ROUTEID
      AND t.ruta.codigo=r.codigo AND p.trackRuta.codigo=t.codigo) 
      OR   p.ruta=ROUTEID)
```

ROUTEID is replacing the id on my code

This worked. I dont like using DISTINCT I know it is costly and it worked for while. Until a USER had like million points on his route and it takes for ever to search even when I am using limits.
I have not had to handle complex db relations in ages so I am really rusty.

I am very fuzzy on how to transform this into a view.  I was using JOINS to do this

```
SELECT *
FROM punto_ruta AS p 
JOIN track_ruta AS t
ON p.id_track_ruta=t.id_track_ruta
JOIN ruta r
ON r.id_ruta=t.id_ruta
right OUTER JOIN ruta r1
ON r1.id_ruta=p.id_ruta
```

I tried also FULL OUTER JOIN but in both cases it is just adding all my Routes at the end.  I am no able to add the points that belong only to a route and not to a track.

Should I combine 2 queries? Like adding this

```
SELECT p.*
FROM punto_ruta AS p
JOIN ruta AS r
On r.id_ruta=p.id_ruta
```

to the query before?

Comment: So If i understand it correctly, Your user will search for Points and you need to show all Routes that these points are under?

Comment: No, they can search for points under a route.  Just that. It usually happens that they want to search for certain points under a date of a route.  Route has track, track have points, there can also be some points that just belong to a Route without a track.

Comment: So just as an example Route 1 can have 2 tracks and each track can have 4 points ( Two of them are A,B) but route 2 can have no tracks but 8 points 2 of them are (A,B)?

Comment: can you post a sample of the data? from 3 tables?

Comment: Your example is kind of correct. Let me show you just with one user case scenario.  A user has usb GPS dongle device or whatever.  Every time the device is turned on it starts a new Track.  So even when the user is doing one Route, a route can have many tracks because the user might have turn it off and on many times.  This device has button for waypoints, waypoints are gps coordinates in case the user might need to point out something on his/her route.

Comment: So in order to make this more simple a route usually has tracks and those tracks have points.  The same route can have also points that belong just to the route and they dont belong to any tracks and they represent a waypoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let independed points have `null` in `track_id`

```
r(id, ...)
t(id, r_id, ...)
p(id, r_id, t_id, ...)

select p.*
  from p
  where p.r_id = ROUTEID
    and p.t_id is null
union all
select p.*
  from t left join p on t.id = p.t_id
  where t.r_id = ROUTEID
```

Comment: It works but I tweeked your answer into this SELECT p.* from punto_ruta AS p, track_ruta AS t, ruta AS r 
 WHERE r.id_ruta=t.id_ruta AND t.id_track_ruta = p.id_track_ruta
 UNION ALL
 SELECT P.*
 FROM punto_ruta AS p, ruta AS r
 WHERE r.id_ruta=p.id_ruta